# Angular UI Bootstrap's Radio Button inside a directive with ng-repeat does not show default value properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Essentially, I have a directive that is used as a 3 way filter using a radio button. Unfortunately, it needs to have a default state and that default state has to actually be shown in the UI, the problem is that although the model is updated properly, the UI is not. Here is a plunkr that demonstrates the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8pljDFyRfInI4Q0qSTmL?p=preview

The directive is used the following way:

```
<filter model="model"/>
```

Where the model is defined as `this.model = { value: {} }` in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated code. 
At first I want to say what `ng-model` directive works only with input elements,

and also I changed the `isActive: 'Yes/No'` to `true/false`

```
// Code goes here

var filters = angular.module('filters', ['ui.bootstrap']);

filters.controller('FilterCtrl', function() {
  this.model = { value: {} };
});

filters.directive('filter', function () {
    return  {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="btn-group">' +
                    '<label ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="btn btn-{{ choice.buttonClass }}" ng-class="{active: choice.value.isActive}"' +

                           'btn-radio="{{ choice.value }}"><i class="fa {{ choice.icon }}"></i>&nbsp;{{ choice.name }}</label>' +
                   '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.choices = [
                { value: { isActive: true }, name: 'Active', buttonClass: 'default', icon: 'fa-circle' },
                { value: null, name: 'Both', buttonClass: 'primary', icon: 'fa-arrows-h' },
                { value: { isActive: false}, name: 'Inactive', buttonClass: 'danger', icon: 'fa-circle-o' },
            ];

            scope.model.value = _.first(_.filter(scope.choices, { value: { isActive: 'Yes' } })).value;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is more of a workaround. In theory it should work just as it is, this is what I am interested in.

Comment: `ng-class="{active: choice.value.isActive}"`